# How to include (a) multipage pdf in the background

Tags: backgrounds

I want to include one/several multipage PDFs as a background to print additional information on it (header, page number, ...)

*Save the [mwe Package documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe) in the directory in order to work*

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\newcommand\invisiblesection[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{section}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}%
  \sectionmark{#1}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headings}

\part{First}
\invisiblesection{My section}

% Only single pages
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\includegraphics[page=1]{mwe}}

.\pagebreak

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\includegraphics[page=2]{mwe}}

.\pagebreak

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\includegraphics[page=3]{mwe}}

.\pagebreak

% ...

\part{Second}
\invisiblesection{My section 2}

% No headers, ...
\includepdf[pages=1-]{mwe}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\includepdf` has the option `pagecommand` for that

Comment: @DG' Thanks! `\includepdf[pagecommand={},pages=1-]{mwe}` solves it!